# How can I use dotnet restore on the command line?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to use `dotnet restore` on the command line. I have installed .NET Core, but when I type `dotnet restore`, I get an error:

> dotnet is not recognized ......

I have tried installing .NET Core 2.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Why such an old version?

Comment: The current version would be **.NET 8** - don't use those really really REALLY old versions of .NET Core anymore - use the current stuff ! Long term, it'll save you a lot of grief and headaches! https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/8.0